# Subsampling to bootstrap multiple pseudo panels

Tags: panel-data, subsampling

I want to create a single observation pseudo panel for a grid-based data set that contains multiple (but unequal) numbers of observations for each grid cell for each year (see below). I need to create a script that will select randomly one observation from each grid-year combination to create a very small panel, write the new panel data to a CSV file and loop to create another randomly sampled single-observation pseudo panel.

I am still learning R - could any one help me figure out what the script would look like? Essentially from the example data below the result should be something like:

1-1-d

1-2-a

1-3-b

2-1-a

2-2-b

2-3-e

Once the panel is constructed (above) it would save the selected data to a CSV file, then repeat the process with another random selection.

Data example:

Cell    Year    Observation

1       1       a

1       1       b

1       1       c

1       1       d

1       2       a

1       2       b

1       3       a

1       3       b

1       3       c

2       1       a

2       1       b

2       1       c

2       1       d

2       2       a

2       2       b

2       2       c

2       3       a

2       3       b

2       3       c

2       3       d

2       3       e

2       3       f

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you were looking for?

```
# create sample data
data <- replicate(1000, c(cell = sample(1:3,1), year = sample(1:3,1), runif(1)))

# create an empty list
obs.list <- list()
# for each unique cell-year pair create a list of observations matching the cell/year
for(i in unique(data[1,])) {
  for(j in unique(data[2,])) {
   obs.list[[length(obs.list) + 1]]  <- which(data[1,]  == i & data[2,] == j)
  }
}

# the nested for loop creates a list of all possible cell year pairs
# if any of the possible pairs has no actual observations, remove it from the list
obs.list <- obs.list[!unlist(lapply(lapply(obs.list,length), "==", 0))]

# generate panel
data[,unlist(lapply(X = obs.list, FUN = sample, 1))]
```